# ogr2ogr incorrectly formating geometry column values

Tags: postgresql, postgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr

On Windows, I'm trying to load in a shapefile (found [here](http://census.cso.ie/censusasp/saps/boundaries/Census2011_Garda_SubDistricts_Nov2013.zip)) to PostGIS in order to be able to do geospatial queries.  Using the following ogr2ogr command:

```
set PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1

ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=my_database user=docker password=docker port=54320" "Census2011_Garda_Subdistricts_Nov2013.shp" -a_srs "EPSG:29902" -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -skip-failures
```

I get no errors or failure on the console. All polygons are now MultiPolygons. ogr2ogr automatically created a table for me that looks like:

[image]

In addition to doing things like querying for points within these features, I'd like to be able to query these that table to return GeoJSON using:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',     'FeatureCollection',
    'features', jsonb_agg(feature)
)
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_build_object(
    'type',       'Feature',
    'id',         ogc_fid,
    'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry)::geometry,
    'properties', to_jsonb(row) - 'gid' - 'geom'
  ) AS feature
  FROM (SELECT * FROM public.census2011_garda_subdistricts_nov2013) row) features;
```

that I found on Stack Overflow [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14514/exporting-feature-geojson-from-postgis).

However, this query gives me the following error:

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
  Hint: "{"" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
```

because the geometry table seems to be wrong:

[image]

Is this a problem with the ogr2ogr command that I can tweak? Is it an issue with the original shapefile? Is the table defined wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faulty cast in your query.

You wrote

```sql
SELECT jsonb_build_object(
...
'geometry',   ST_AsGeoJSON(wkb_geometry)::geometry,
```

which basically creates a geojson that you try to cast back to a geometry, which fails.

You can just remove this cast, or cast it to `jsonb` as in the original query.